# If the mind is not divisible and the brain is divisible, then it logically follows that mind and brain are not the same thing

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

If the mind is not divisible and the brain is divisible, then it logically follows that mind and brain are not the same thing.

Group of answer choices

True

False

Comment: People talk to themselves all the time, making exchanges in their internal dialog.  They struggle with their own inconsistent reactions to the same facts.  They surprise themselves. So in what sense is the mind not divisible?

Comment: That much is obvious, but beside the point, statue and its shape are also not the same thing. The relevant question is whether the mind is related to the brain like the shape to the statue.

Comment: The question is one of semantical juggling. This isn't a philosophical question, it's a logical puzzle/assertion which happens to use a philosophical theme.

Comment: Your question is an "if clause" question, which in this case is of type 2 or unreal situation, at least clinically. Clinically, when 2 parts of the brain are divided and can't communicate, the corresponding parts of the mind are divided and can't communicate, either. There many clinical syndromes demostrating these mental divisions, such as split-brain syndrome, conduction aphasia, and pseudobulbar affect. This can happen in stroke, injury, multiple sclerosis, etc. that destroy the neural tracts between parts of the brain and effectively divide them ... and the corresponding parts of the mind.

Comment: user287279 is certainly right, and didn't even include the internal conflicts of nonpathic human minds

Comment: I am of two minds about this question. Still, dividing a brain is counter-indicated since the result is very often no longer a functioning brain.

Comment: A computer program will not function if divided.  Computer memory can be divided.  Therefore a computer program is not resident in computer memory.  T/F?

Comment: @Ask About Monica Computer programs are stored in computer memory (RAM, ROM, hard disk, flas drive, etc.) and executed from there. Although they may be physically divided and scattered in many parts of the storage, normally, they're functionally continuous and executed sequentially in a continuous manner. They'll not function only if they're functionally divided by miscodes or software bugs.

Comment: Similarly, memory of something may be scattered all over a computer memory storage but will function if it's functionally continous. But it will not function, even if it's physically continuous on a memory storage, if it's functionally divided by miscodes or bugs that disrupt the storage.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the mind and the brain are identical: one and the same thing. All that your question need show in that case is that we use incommensurable languages. When we talk in one way we talk of neurons and synapses and so on; when we talk in another we talk of beliefs and inferences. These languages do not map on to each other and are not inter-translatable. We can intelligibly talk of dividing a neuron but not of dividing a belief. That shows nothing about the relation of mind and brain.

Consider a parallel: a mural. We can describe the mural geometrically in terms of circles, angles, arcs and the rest; we can also describe it aesthetically in terms of apt colouring, novel imagery, symbolic significance. Geometrical language is incommensurable with aesthetic language but they are both describing exactly one and the same thng - the mural.

I haven't shown that mind and brain are identical but I have shown that the incommensurability of mind-talk and brain-talk, on which your question relies, does not prove that they are not identical.